# How to run groovy scripts on slave node by passing the groovy script file path in jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes-pod

I have configured jenkins using its docker image to scale and deploy it on a kubernetes cluster (minikube) using the kubernetes plugin and successfully able to generate the slaves dynamically. But I am not able to run groovy scripts by passing the file path of the the groovy file on the slave. I have tried using SSH and scp command but not able to run the scripts on slave node. Any other idea??

To try I created a sample groovy file on the slave node and gave its path to the groovy plugin and tried to build the job which works. Can we create a file in our local system and make it run on the slave node.

Comment: How are you calling groovy, System groovy (available only on master) or Groovy script ? Any security alerts? What (error) msgs?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using Groovy Script and not system groovy. By the way, now I am able to run groovy script on slave node using the concept of Volumes in kubernetes

Comment: Will you be able to explain on this more, do we mount master groovy path in slave pod?